# Zend Framework 2 - Get Controller and Action name in Layout

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i have tried to get controller name and action name in layout file. But could not. In ZF1, we have used Front Controller instance to get the controller and action name. I have surfed the websites a lot. But there is no solution. How can i get in ZF2?

Answer (score 5):

Controllers and their view scripts are decoupled. In fact, there could be several controllers involved in a single request.

If you want the controller and action the request got dispatched to, you can inject them by hooking into the dispatch event and inject the controller and action name in the attached ViewModel.

One way of doing that is inside the Bootstrap Event which should be in the Module class.

```php
public function onBootstrap(\Zend\EventManager\EventInterface $e)
{
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $app->getEventManager()->attach(
        'dispatch',
        function($e) {
            $routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();
            $viewModel = $e->getViewModel();
            $viewModel->setVariable('controller', $routeMatch->getParam('controller'));
            $viewModel->setVariable('action', $routeMatch->getParam('action'));
        },
        -100
    );
```

Comment: First of all, thasnk. i have checked. But i am getting the following error. Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for modulename' in /var/www/app/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:452 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/app/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php(110): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('modulename', true)

Comment: Your are asking the the serviceManager to get service 'modulename' somewhere? Looks like its not related to what you were asking for here.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 'modulename' is my module. I have used the above code in that module. After that i am getting the above error.

Comment: What does the -100 mean?

Comment: It's the priority. ZF2's DispatchListener is registered with priority 1, so any listener registered with a higher priority is executed before and a lower number after ZF2's DispatchListener. Meaning in this case that the function is executed after the request is dispatched and we have a ViewModel that's ready to be rendered. The Event queue is implemented using the [SplPriorityQueue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splpriorityqueue.php)

Answer (score 0):

I got the above answer to work but I had to use the sharedManager to pass on the view to the controller

```
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $app->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach(
        __NAMESPACE__,
        'dispatch',
        function($e) {
            $routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();
            $viewModel = $e->getViewModel();
            $viewModel->setVariable('controller', $routeMatch->getParam('controller'));
            $viewModel->setVariable('action', $routeMatch->getParam('action'));
            $controller = $e->getTarget();
            $controller->view = $viewModel;
        },
        100
    );
```

If I wanted to use the above answer as is I had to do

```
    $this->getEvent('dispatch')->getViewModel()
```

in the controller

Comment: Thanks, But, where we have to place this code in my actions. $this->getEvent('dispatch')->getViewModel()